# Error while Creating Angular JS Jasmine Test Case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating Angular JS Jasmine Test Case. My code JS as follows:-

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("PatientDefectManagementCtrl", function ($scope, angularService) {
$scope.getNextAccountInfo = function () {
    $scope.data = {message: 'Hello'};
}
});
```

**I am getting error : Error: [ng:areq]**

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/ng/areq?p0=PatientDefectManagementCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined**

My Test Case as follows:-

```
describe('Patient Defect Management Testing ', function () {

    module('myApp');

    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));


    describe('Message Management', function () {
        it('NextAccountDetails', function () {
            var $scope = {};
           var controller = $controller('PatientDefectManagementCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
            $scope.Message = 'Hello';

            $scope.getNextAccountInfo();
            expect($scope.Message).toBe('Hello');

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you using Karma? If yes, can you post the content here as well?

Comment: I am using Jasmine